# Restore dump on the remote machine

Tags: postgresql, dump, remote-server, pg-restore

I've got my own machine with postgres dmp file, which I want to restore on the remote virtual machine (e.g. ip is 192.168.0.190 and postgres port is 5432) in my network. Is it possible to restore this dump using pg_restore without copying dump to remote machine? Because the size of dump about 12GB and the disk space on the virtual machine is 20GB.
Thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can run a restore over the network without copying the dump to the remote host.

Just invoke `pg_restore` with `-h <hostname>` and `-p <port>` (and probably `-U <username>` to authenticate as different user) on the host you got the dump file, for example:

```
pg_restore -h 192.168.0.190 -p 5432 -d databasename -U myuser mydump.dump
```

**References:**

- [pg_restore documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-pgrestore.html)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I'm trying like this pg_restore -i -h 192.168.1.190 -p 5432 -U postgres -d MFC_sara -v /home/develop/BD_Dumps/Saratov.dmp ; But after this command it's needed to input some password for destination database. And I don't know it, on virtual machine I just create db like createdb -T template0 MFC_sara

Comment: If you want to access from a remote machine you will need password authentication (or any other non-local authentication). Create a user and assign privileges for the database. Or if this is no production environment, create a superuser with password: `createuser -P -s someusername`

Answer (score 18):

Alternatively, you can use psql:

`psql -h 192.168.0.190 -p 5432 -d <dbname> -U <username> -W -f mydump.dump`

Answer (score 9):

An example for a remote RDS instance on AWS

```
psql -h  mydb.dsdreetr34.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -d mydbname -U mydbuser -W -f  mydatabase-dump.sql

  -f, --file=FILENAME      execute commands from file, then exit
  -W, --password           force password prompt (should happen automatically)
```

Comment: This worked! but inserting 10 rows at a time can we increase size

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the password parameter in your script before "pg_restore" using PGPASSWORD="your_database_password"

Answer (score 1):

I run this and works to me:

```
    scp backup.dump user@remotemachine:~

    ssh user@remotemachine "pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U databaseuser -W -F c -d databasename -v backup.dump"
```

You can write a script to automate this.