# How to restore postgres within a docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker, restore

I create backups like this: `docker exec DOCKER pg_dump -U USER -F t DB | gzip > ./FILE.tar.gz`

What's the best way to restore the database given that the database runs within a container?

Comment: well, you can point a volume containing the backup at first run and then call `pg_restore`, but that doesn't have to go through docker way so you can do it [remotely](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26378243/1233686)

Comment: cool, but as far as I understand, my problem is that I cannot get the unpacking of the compressed file right. Any ideas?

Comment: would `gunzip < backup.tar.gz | pg_restore -F t ..` help for your case?

Comment: I think we're very close but something is missing. the above command just prints out the (uncompressed) content of the file.

Comment: just to be more explicit `gunzip < backup.tar.gz | pg_restore -U USER -F t DB`. Other than the output, have you connect and check if any data has written?

Comment: cool, it works but I had to add `-d` before `DB`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your case:

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER> gunzip < backup.tar.gz | pg_restore -U <USER> -F t -d <DB>
```

Remote restore is also available if your container is public facing and remote connections are allowed in `pg_hba.conf` for postresql:

```
gunzip < backup.tar.gz | pg_restore -U <USER> -F t -d <DB> -h <HOST_IP> -p 5432
```

As a rule of thumb, it is good idea to document your backup and restore commands specific to the project.

Comment: Lovely docker expertise!

Comment: @hurturk Oddly, I can get the backup the OP posted to work just fine:

docker exec postgres-local-15 pg_dump -U postgres -F t dvdrental | gzip > /Users/me/Downloads/dvdrental.tar.gz

But I get "zsh: command not found: pg_restore" when trying either of your methods to restore, like so:

docker exec postgres-local-15 gunzip < /Users/me/Downloads/dvdrental.tar | pg_restore -U postgres -F t -d dvdrental

-or-

gunzip < /Users/me/Downloads/dvdrental.tar | pg_restore -U postgres -F t -d dvdrental -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432

Could the "zsh" mean that it's looking on my local for pg_restore?

Answer (score 0):

How take backup of the data which is existing in the running PostgreSQL container

---

1. Create some folder in your root

   ```
   mkdir -p '/myfolder/bdbackup'
   ```
2. download the postgres  image which you are using and execute the following command

   ```
   docker run --name demo1 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=passowrd -v /myfolder/bdbackup:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres 

   docker exec -it demo1 psql -U postgres
   ```
3. Back up will be stored in the following folder `/myfolder/bdbackup`
4. you can kill the container and stop the container any time but data will be stored in the host.
5. and once again re-run the postgres the container with same command

   ```
   docker run --name demo2 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=passowrd -v /myfolder/bdbackup:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres 

   docker exec -it demo1 psql -U postgres
   ```

   and execute following query `select * from emp;`
6. you can see the data has restored...

Comment: How to do it with volume instead of mount?